# How to check if user has denied android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

My application request to check if the user has not allowed starting foreground service. But

```
if (checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
 //always true ??? but the user has not allowed this permission
}
```

Comment: there is no need to check it , it is a normal permission it will be permitted automatically when app is installed

Comment: Have you found a solution?  Is **FOREGROUND_SERVICE** supposed to be a runtime permission.

Answer (score 2):

> Apps wanting to use foreground services must now request the
>   FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission first. This is a normal permission, so
>   the system automatically grants it to the requesting app. Starting a
>   foreground service without the permission throws a SecurityException.

The solution is to just add the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest ...>
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
     ...
     <application ...>
     ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: What happens if we don't request this permission?

Comment: Your foreground service will not work as it will not show a notification @IgorGanapolsky

Comment: I thought Google did away with Foreground Services in favor of Work Manager?

Answer (score 2):

As per android document if the permission is normal then no need to ask it dynamically and if permission dangerous permissions then you need to ask it dynamically

> **From android Document:** If your app lists normal permissions in its
>   manifest (that is, permissions that don't pose much risk to the user's
>   privacy or the device's operation), the system automatically grants
>   those permissions to your app.
>
> If your app lists dangerous permissions in its manifest (that is,
>   permissions that could potentially affect the user's privacy or the
>   device's normal operation), such as the SEND_SMS permission above, the
>   user must explicitly agree to grant those permissions.
>   [Permissions overview Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

Just declare bellow permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have set this permission in my manifest. But my test phone (XIOAMI redmi note 8 with Android 9) ask user validation to denied or granted.